# Embedding Third Party Fonts as resource for Win32 Application

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, embedded-resource

I was wondering how i can embed a third party font into my app( and use it ) so i can distribute my app with the font of my choice for users who do not have the font installed on their systems. Is this possible, or do i have to distribute the font if i want the users to be able to use the font in question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you assume that you do have the legal permission to distribute the font?

Comment: By 'embed', do you mean the font must be part of the executable? Or can you simply package it as just another file with your application?

Answer (score 2):

Stick the actual font file into a [User-Defined Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381054(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Hi @Billy : I tried that and i got an Error from the Resource Compiler. The font file's license is liberal, its a free font. It's and OpenType type font.

@Mark: I was actually trying to find a way where i didnt have to distribute the actual file as part of the package, is there any way to avoid this?

I may have found a solution and it consists of using the TTEmbedFont function and some GDI magic, i will try this and report. If anyone else has input i'm all ears :) or eyes.

Comment: @gandolf: What is the error you got from the resource compiler? We can't help troubleshoot if you don't let us know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Very few fonts will have a license that allows this. Even a free font should be checked.

You can use CreateScalableFontResource and AddFontResource to make a font file available to your application. The font must be available as a separate file for this to work.

Comment: In our application we are using "Segoe UI Light", can i embed it in EXE (i.e we are not including font file as separate file in package, font file is part of EXE). embedding like this is having an licence issue