# Embed font in MFC

Tags: c++, user-interface, fonts, mfc, gdi+

I have an application created with MFC. It uses a not so common font that is rendered with GDI+. I want to keep using that font since it fits in with the rest of the design. My application have to be self-contained though, i.e. only an .exe file with no dependencies. So I'm wondering if there is anyway to embed the font in the program as a resource and use the GDI+ API to render it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233993/embedding-third-party-fonts-as-resource-for-win32-application

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. That question seems give two answers but both of them have problems. However, it does give me an idea, combining both answers, should I stick it in a custom resource and create the font using CreateScalableFontResource on the fly?